# Linq query to merge overlapping elements

Tags: c#, linq

I have this class representing a period of time:

```
    public class Period
    {
        public Period(DateTime dateFrom)
        {
            DateFrom = dateFrom;
        }

        public Period(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime? dateTo)
        {
            DateFrom = dateFrom;
            DateTo = dateTo;
        }

        public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateTo { get; set; }


        public bool IsOverlapping(Period other)
        {
            if (!DateTo.HasValue)
            {
                return DateFrom <= other.DateTo.Value;
            }

            if (!other.DateTo.HasValue)
            {
                return other.DateFrom <= DateTo.Value;
            }

            return DateFrom <= other.DateTo.Value && other.DateFrom <= DateTo.Value;
        }

        public bool IsFinite => DateTo.HasValue;

        public bool IsInfinite => !IsFinite;

        protected bool Equals(Period other)
        {
            return DateFrom.Equals(other.DateFrom) && Nullable.Equals(DateTo, other.DateTo);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
            return Equals((Period) obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return HashCode.Combine(DateFrom, DateTo);
        }
    }
```

Now a have a list of periods and for each of them I have to perform an network call so to minimize them I decide to merge all overlapping periods.

So a list like that :

- 2020-01-01 -> 2020-01-10
- 2020-02-05 -> 2020-02-10
- 2020-02-07 -> 2020-02-15
- 2020-02-13 -> 2020-02-20
- 2020-03-01 -> 2020-03-10
- 2020-03-25 -> 2020-03-31
- 2020-03-30 ->

Should become :

- 2020-01-01 -> 2020-01-10
- 2020-02-05 -> 2020-02-20
- 2020-03-01 -> 2020-03-10
- 2020-03-25 ->

I tried this code

```
    public static IEnumerable<Period> Implementation(IEnumerable<Period> periods)
    {
        return periods.OrderBy(p => p.DateFrom)
            .Aggregate(new List<Period>(), (ps, p) =>
            {
                if (!ps.Any())
                {
                    ps.Add(p);
                    return ps;
                }

                var last = ps.Last();
                if (last.IsOverlapping(p))
                {
                    if (last.IsInfinite || p.IsInfinite)
                    {
                        ps[ps.Count() - 1] = new Period(DateTimeHelpers.Min(last.DateFrom, p.DateFrom), null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ps[ps.Count() - 1] = new Period(DateTimeHelpers.Min(last.DateFrom, p.DateFrom),
                            DateTimeHelpers.Max(last.DateTo.Value, p.DateTo.Value));
                    }

                    return ps;
                }

                ps.Add(p);
                return ps;

            });
    }
```

Here is the DateTimeHelpers I'm using :

```
public class DateTimeHelpers
{
    public static DateTime Max(DateTime first, DateTime second)
    {
        return first <= second
            ? second
            : first;
    }

    public static DateTime Min(DateTime first, DateTime second)
    {
        return first >= second
            ? second
            : first;
    }
}
```

It's working properly but I'm not satisfied with it so I wonder if there is a more performant/elegant/readable way to do it ?

I'm not talking about just refactoring to extract some methods but a fundamentally different solution, it's possible I missed a useful LINQ operator.

Here is my test if you want to reproduce it (MsTest + FluentAssertions). The period are not in the right order to ensure it will be take care of by the method itself:

```
        // Arrange
        var periods = new List<Period>()
        {
            new Period(new DateTime(2020, 2, 13), new DateTime(2020, 2, 20)),
            new Period(new DateTime(2020, 3, 1), new DateTime(2020, 3, 10)),
            new Period(new DateTime(2020, 3, 25), new DateTime(2020, 3, 31)),
            new Period(new DateTime(2020, 3, 30)),
            new Period(new DateTime(2020, 1, 1), new DateTime(2020, 1, 10)),
            new Period(new DateTime(2020, 2, 5), new DateTime(2020, 2, 10)),
            new Period(new DateTime(2020, 2, 7), new DateTime(2020, 2, 15))
        };

        // Act
        var mergedPeriods = Implementation(periods);

        // Assert
        mergedPeriods.Should().HaveCount(4);
        mergedPeriods[0].Should().Be(new Period(new DateTime(2020, 1, 1), new DateTime(2020, 1, 10)));
        mergedPeriods[1].Should().Be(new Period(new DateTime(2020, 2, 5), new DateTime(2020, 2, 20)));
        mergedPeriods[2].Should().Be(new Period(new DateTime(2020, 3, 1), new DateTime(2020, 3, 10)));
        mergedPeriods[3].Should().Be(new Period(new DateTime(2020, 3, 25)));
```

Comment: I voted to close as the `Period` class, as presented, doesn't compile and therefore can't be reviewed.

Comment: Well... For this example I made the DateFrom not nullable and I forgot to remove the ".Value" in the code. It's maybe a bit excessive to say the code can't be reviewed...
I will update it to also provide the Equals/GetHashCode I guess...

Comment: I will remove my close vote now that it has been updated to work.

Comment: Your `Aggreate` still does not compile: `DateFrom` does not have `Value`.  Please also indicate which `DateTimeHelpers` nuget package are you using.

Comment: I remove the .Value (...) and add my helpers implementation.

Comment: Is there really a reason to want better performance? We all want that, but if performance is good enough there's not need to make it better, which often means that readability is 
sacrificed for all kinds of ugly premature optimizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my observations:

#### `Period`

- `public Period(DateTime dateFrom)`: Do not repeat yourself. Just call the other ctor:

```cs
public Period(DateTime dateFrom) 
    : this(dateFrom, null)
{ }
```

- `public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }`: Because you have a ctor, where you specify its value that's why you don't need public setter:

```cs
public DateTime DateFrom { get; }
public DateTime? DateTo { get; }
```

- `return DateFrom <= other.DateTo.Value;`: `other.DateTo` can be null, so this could result an `InvalidOperationException`. Include null check as well:

```cs
if (!DateTo.HasValue)
{
    return other.DateTo != null && DateFrom <= other.DateTo.Value;
}
```

- `IsFinite`: It is used only by the `IsInfinite`, so you could merge them:

```cs
public bool IsInfinite => !DateTo.HasValue;
```

- `Equals` and `GetHashCode`: The default ones are good, you don't need to override them.

So, the `Period` class after refactor:

```cs
public class Period
{
    public Period(DateTime dateFrom)
        : this(dateFrom, null)
    { }

    public Period(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime? dateTo)
    {
        DateFrom = dateFrom;
        DateTo = dateTo;
    }

    public DateTime DateFrom { get; }
    public DateTime? DateTo { get; }

    public bool IsOverlapping(Period other)
    {
        if (!DateTo.HasValue)
        {
            return other.DateTo != null && DateFrom <= other.DateTo.Value;
        }

        if (!other.DateTo.HasValue)
        {
            return other.DateFrom <= DateTo.Value;
        }

        return DateFrom <= other.DateTo.Value && other.DateFrom <= DateTo.Value;
    }

    public bool IsInfinite => !DateTo.HasValue;
}
```

---

#### `DateTimeHelpers`

- `Min`: I think the `GetEarlier` name would be more expressive. Also you can easily modify it to become an extension method:

```cs
public static DateTime GetEarlier(this DateTime first, DateTime second)
    => first >= second ? second : first;
```

- `Max` It is used against `DateTo` properties. So, I would suggest to rename it to `GetLater` and use `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime`:

```cs
public static DateTime? GetLater(this DateTime? first, DateTime? second)
    => first <= second ? second : first;
```

- `Implementation`: This name is way too generic. I would suggest to change it to be an extension method and name it like `Merge` or `Consolidate` or whatver:

```cs
public static IReadOnlyCollection<Period> Merge(this IEnumerable<Period> periods)
{

}
```

- When they are not overlapping: I would suggest to handle that case right after the empty collection case. With this approach you have to early exits  inside the Aggregator

```cs
periods
    .OrderBy(period => period.DateFrom)
    .Aggregate(new List<Period>(),
        (mergedPeriods, period) =>
        {
            if (!mergedPeriods.Any())
            {
                mergedPeriods.Add(period);
                return mergedPeriods;
            }

            var latest = mergedPeriods.Last();
            if (!latest.IsOverlapping(period))
            {
                mergedPeriods.Add(period);
                return mergedPeriods;
            }
            
            //When overlapping
        });
```

- When they are overlapping: Here you have several repeated commands The repetition can be refactored like this:

```cs
DateTime from = latest.DateFrom.GetEarlier(period.DateFrom);
DateTime? to = null;
if (!latest.IsInfinite && !period.IsInfinite)
{
    to = latest.DateTo.GetLater(period.DateTo);
}

mergedPeriods[^1] = new Period(from, to);
return mergedPeriods;
```

- Instead of calculating the `from` in both cases here we calculate only once
- Instead of accessing the last element in both cases here we access it only once

  - We use here [C# 8's new syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges#systemindex): `[^1]`
- Instead of calling the ctor in both cases here we call it only once
- Instead of having two branches now can handle the special case with a single branch

So, the `Helper` class after refactor:

```cs
public static class Helpers
{
    public static DateTime GetEarlier(this DateTime first, DateTime second)
        => first >= second ? second : first;

    public static DateTime? GetLater(this DateTime? first, DateTime? second)
        => first <= second ? second : first;

    public static IReadOnlyCollection<Period> Merge(this IEnumerable<Period> periods)
        => periods
            .OrderBy(period => period.DateFrom)
            .Aggregate(new List<Period>(),
                (mergedPeriods, period) =>
                {
                    if (!mergedPeriods.Any())
                    {
                        mergedPeriods.Add(period);
                        return mergedPeriods;
                    }

                    var latest = mergedPeriods.Last();
                    if (!latest.IsOverlapping(period))
                    {
                        mergedPeriods.Add(period);
                        return mergedPeriods;
                    }

                    DateTime from = latest.DateFrom.GetEarlier(period.DateFrom);
                    DateTime? to = null;
                    if (!latest.IsInfinite && !period.IsInfinite)
                    {
                        to = latest.DateTo.GetLater(period.DateTo);
                    }

                    mergedPeriods[^1] = new Period(from, to);
                    return mergedPeriods;
                });
}
```

---

#### Usage is this simple

```cs
foreach (var period in periods.Merge())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{period.DateFrom:M} => {period.DateTo:M}");
}
```

Comment: I missed your answer. I was more looking into a different type of algorithm for the "merge" method but your remarks are relevant :-)